# How to place spheres in a half circle shape between 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating small spheres between two given points. However it always generates in a straight line. Is it possible that the spheres can start generating as a curve from Point A to Point B?

I am defining how many spheres should be generated between two points by defining `NumberOfSegments`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GeneratePoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PointA; 
    public Transform PointB; 
    public float NumberOfSegments = 3; 
    public float AlongThePath = .25f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
       StartCoroutine(StartSpheringOut());
    }

    IEnumerator StartSpheringOut()
    {
        NumberOfSegments += 1;// since we are skipping 1st placement since its the same as starting point we increase the number by 1 
        AlongThePath = 1 / (NumberOfSegments);//% along the path

        for (int i = 1; i < NumberOfSegments; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
            Vector3 CreatPosition = PointA.position + (PointB.position - PointA.position) * (AlongThePath * i);

            GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            sphere.transform.position = CreatPosition;
            sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define what a `curve from Point A to Point B` is ... there are multiple ways to define a curve mathematically (like e.g. [Bezier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) or [Nurbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline)) but I don't know any that is based on only **2** input points ...

Comment: @derHugo yeah I do not think without bezier i can generate a curve. If say without bezier I want to do, then lets say the distance between point A and B is 2 meters, so I would have to generate 5-10 points around it so it looks like a curve.

Comment: so you basically mean you create a half-circle where the center lies in the middle between A and B?

Comment: @derHugo yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually almost exists already in the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CircleFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
   // Instantiates prefabs in a circle formation
   public GameObject prefab;
   public int numberOfObjects = 20;
   public float radius = 5f;

   void Start()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
       {
           float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
           float x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
           float z = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
           Vector3 pos = transform.position + new Vector3(x, 0, z);
           float angleDegrees = -angle*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
           Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleDegrees, 0);
           Instantiate(prefab, pos, rot);
       }
   }
}
```

You can use this for starters and then adjust it to your needs in order to make it work in general. So since you only want the half of the circle all you have to do is basically to devide the `angle` by `2` and add the `pointA` and `pointB` in order to calculate the center position. Also if both positions are not in the same XZ-plane you would have to rotate the entire circle:

```
public GameObject A;
public GameObject B;

public int amount;

[ContextMenu("PlaceSpheres()")]
privtae void DebugPlace()
{
    PlaceSpheres(A.transform.position, B.transform.position, amount);
}

public void PlaceSpheres(Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB, int numberOfObjects)
{
    // get circle center and radius
    var radius = Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / 2f;
    var centerPos = (posA + posB) / 2f;

    // get a rotation that looks in the direction
    // posA -> posB
    var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((posB - posA).normalized);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        // Max angle is 180° (= Mathf.PI in rad) not 360° (= Mathf.PI * 2 in rad)
        //          |
        //          |    don't place the first object exactly on posA 
        //          |    but start already with an offset
        //          |    (remove the +1 if you want to start at posA instead)
        //          |               |
        //          |               |     don't place the last object on posB 
        //          |               |     but end one offset before
        //          |               |     (remove the +1 if you want to end 
        //          |               |     exactly a posB instead)
        //          |               |                       |
        //          V               V                       V
        var angle = Mathf.PI * (i + 1) / (numberOfObjects + 1f);
        var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
        var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
        var pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
        pos = centerDirection * pos;

        var sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = centerPos + pos;
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I have one query, as a part 2 question. How do I create just one sphere that travels in this arc position from Point A to Point B and from Point B to Point A in a loop?

Comment: @MohammedSaifSDK this is not the scope of your question anymore! In short: Instead of instantiating new objects rather store the positions in a List and then travel between the points of that list.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try doing that and if I face difficulty I will ask as a new question.