# Create just one sphere that travels between two points in a loop within a half circle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In relation to the question asked here ([How to place spheres in a half circle shape between 2 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738064/how-to-place-spheres-in-a-half-circle-shape-between-2-points)) that generates spheres between two points A and B.
How do I create just one sphere that moves from Point A to Point B and then back from Point B to Point A in a loop cycle? How do I use Lerp in this context?

I have tried making the sphere move in the angle (half circle) described in the below code but it always moves in a straight line.

The below code generates spheres between two points.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetCurves : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;

    public int amount;

    [ContextMenu("PlaceSpheres()")]
    public void Start()
    {
        PlaceSpheres(A.transform.position, B.transform.position, amount);
    }

    public void PlaceSpheres(Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB, int numberOfObjects)
    {
        // get circle center and radius
        var radius = Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / 2f;
        var centerPos = (posA + posB) / 2f;

        // get a rotation that looks in the direction
        // posA -> posB
        var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((posB - posA).normalized);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {

            var angle = Mathf.PI * (i+1) / (numberOfObjects + 1); //180 degrees
            var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
            var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
            var pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
            // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
            pos = centerDirection * pos;

            var sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            sphere.transform.position = centerPos + pos;
            sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        }
    }
}
```

The below script I had created that makes an object move between two points in a loop but only in a straight line. How do I make it move in a curve (180 degrees)?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RunInLoop : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 0.25f;
    public Transform PointA;
    public Transform PointB;
    private Vector3 origin;
    private bool backToOrigin;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = PointA.transform.position;
        origin = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, backToOrigin ? origin : PointB.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            // if one of the two positions is reached invert the flag
            if (transform.position == PointB.transform.position || transform.position == origin)
            {
                backToOrigin = !backToOrigin;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code only runs once and places items in a sphere. it does not do any moving..  Is this some form of school homework? There seem to be a lot of questions  this week about placing things and moving them in an arc

Comment: Yeah this code just places number of spheres between two points. I have tried putting just one sphere to move between the two points but it does not follow the path I am creating. No definitely not school homework, I am trying to do new things on Unity and this is where I am stuck at.

Comment: You'd need to show how you were trying to move it.  The problem really isnt unity but the logic of how to move along the path

Comment: I have updated the post with the new script that makes object move from Point A to B and back in a loop. (in a straight line)

Comment: correct it will move in a straight line because thats what you told it to do. You need to find the point on the arc and move to that, not just between a->b

Comment: Yes I am creating the arc in the first script "GetCurves". I just need help in integrating it on the second script.

Comment: to be honest you dont really need that first code so much, but.. there doesnt seem to be an sign of trying..

Comment: @BugFinder I have tried to create the arc but it just does not seem to follow the path which is why I removed the arc creation from the second script and kept it on the first script itself..

Comment: because movetowards is a striaghtline.. and no where do you tell it any different

Comment: I honestly did not know movetowards is used only for a straight line. I just thought if i create the arc and give movetowards position to Point B position as `posB = centerDirection * posB;` it should work

Comment: then you really do need to read the unity docs if you werent aware of what the function you are using does.  You are also not creating an arc, that first code places item "in" an arc, but there is no arc.. once there they have no concept of why you placed them there.. they will not use that later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195495/discussion-between-mohammed-saif-s-d-k-and-bugfinder).

Comment: I cannot use chat at work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution using your code

As I told you in [my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56738606/7111561) that provided your first code you should store them in a list and then make the object move between them:

```
public class GetCurves : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;

    public int amount;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    private Transform sphere;
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private bool movingForward = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere).transform;
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);

        GeneratePositions(A.transform.position, B.transform.position, amount);

        sphere.position = positions[0];
    }

    private void GeneratePositions(Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB, int numberOfObjects)
    {
        // get circle center and radius
        var radius = Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / 2f;
        var centerPos = (posA + posB) / 2f;

        // get a rotation that looks in the direction
        // posA -> posB
        var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((posB - posA).normalized);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {

            var angle = Mathf.PI * (i + 1) / (numberOfObjects + 1); //180 degrees
            var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
            var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
            var pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
            // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
            pos = centerDirection * pos;

            // store them in a list this time
            positions.Add(centerPos + pos);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (positions == null || positions.Count == 0) return;

        // == for Vectors works with precision of 0.00001
        // if you need a better precision instead use
        //if(!Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(sphere.position, positions[currentIndex]), 0f))
        if (sphere.position != positions[currentIndex])
        {
            sphere.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(sphere.transform.position, positions[currentIndex], moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            return;
        }

        // once the position is reached select the next index
        if (movingForward)
        {
            if (currentIndex + 1 < positions.Count)
            {
                currentIndex++;
            }
            else if (currentIndex + 1 >= positions.Count)
            {
                currentIndex--;
                movingForward = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentIndex - 1 >= 0)
            {
                currentIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentIndex++;
                movingForward = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to stick to Single-Responsibility-Principles you could also seperate the movement from the list generation like e.g.

```
public class GetCurves : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;

    public int amount;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private void Start()
    {
        GeneratePositions(A.transform.position, B.transform.position, amount);
    }

    private void GeneratePositions(Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB, int numberOfObjects)
    {
        // get circle center and radius
        var radius = Vector3.Distance(posA, posB) / 2f;
        var centerPos = (posA + posB) / 2f;

        // get a rotation that looks in the direction
        // posA -> posB
        var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((posB - posA).normalized);

        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();    

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {

            var angle = Mathf.PI * (i + 1) / (numberOfObjects + 1); //180 degrees
            var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
            var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
            var pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
            // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
            pos = centerDirection * pos;

            // store them in a list this time
            positions.Add(centerPos + pos);
        }

        var sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);

        var movement = sphere.AddComponent<MoveBetweenPoints>();
        movement.positions = positions;
        movement.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
    }
```

and in a seperate script

```
public class MoveBetweenPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    public float moveSpeed;

    privtae bool movingForward = true;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (positions == null || positions.Count == 0) return;

        // == for Vectors works with precision of 0.00001
        // if you need a better precision instead use
        //if(!Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(sphere.position, positions[currentIndex]), 0f))
        if (sphere.position != positions[currentIndex])
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positions[currentIndex], moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            return;
        }

        // once the position is reached select the next index
        if (movingForward)
        {
            if (currentIndex + 1 < positions.Count)
            {
                currentIndex++;
            }
            else if (currentIndex + 1 >= positions.Count)
            {
                currentIndex--;
                movingForward = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentIndex - 1 >= 0)
            {
                currentIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentIndex++;
                movingForward = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

#### Actual Solution

However, if you want a smooth movement on a circle curve ... why even reduce that circle curcve to a certain amount of positions? You could directly moove according to the angle between `0°` and `180°` like this:

```
public class GetCurves : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;
    // now in Angles per second
    public float moveSpeed;

    private Transform sphere;
    private bool movingForward = true;
    private float angle;

    private void Start()
    {
        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere).transform;
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (movingForward)
        {
            angle += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            angle -= moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (angle < 0)
        {
            angle = 0;
            movingForward = true;
        }
        else if (angle > 180)
        {
            angle = 180;
            movingForward = false;
        }

        // get circle center and radius
        var radius = Vector3.Distance(A.transform.position, B.transform.position) / 2f;
        var centerPos = (A.transform.position + B.transform.position) / 2f;

        // get a rotation that looks in the direction
        // posA -> posB
        var centerDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation((B.transform.position - A.transform.position).normalized);

        var x = Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * radius;
        var z = Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * radius;
        var pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        // Rotate the pos vector according to the centerDirection
        pos = centerDirection * pos;

        sphere.position = centerPos + pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the changes and this code, I have updated few more changes such as Vector3.MoveTowards and few others. I have noticed that the sphere moves from one place ahead of Point A (posA.position + 1) and ends one place before Point B (posB.position -1). What changes can I do in the code that makes the sphere start exactly at Point A and end exactly at Point B?

Comment: I also mentioned this in comments in the original answer. I intentionally started with an offset from A and ended one offset before B. You can remove the two `+1` in the line `var angle = Mathf.PI * (i + 1) / (numberOfObjects + 1);` and it has to be `if (currentIndex - 1 >= 0)` just fixed this one as well

Comment: Yes I followed the same instructions as you gave in the previous post, yet the sphere never reaches the two given points.

Comment: oh yeah it should with `var angle = Mathf.PI * i / (numberOfObjects - 1);` ([gif](https://imgur.com/2wW6HW2))

Comment: btw see the last update under `Actual Solution` ... if anyway yu don't want to place various objects but only move one .. then why even store a certain set of positions? You could simply directly move along the original curve

Comment: Why not just use movearound? and go back/forth?