# How to spawn evenly spaced game objects and move them in a circular path?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, lerp

I don't know why my code doesn't work as intended!

when I put speed = 1, it works fine. But if I increase the speed, it doesn't work.

I tried to use `FixedUpdate` too on the circle class, but it didn't fix the issue.

I don't know what else I have to do.

Actual Behavior:
[image: Link for actual behavior]

Expected Behavior:
[image: Link for expected behavior]

Orbit Class:

```c#
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Circle circlePrefab;
     public Vector2 centerPoint = Vector2.zero;
     [Range(3, 360)] public int segments = 5;
     public float xRadius = 2f;
     public float yRadius = 2f;
     public int numberOfCircles = 0;
     public float speed = 0f;

     private Vector2 initPosition = new Vector2(0, 2f);
     private Vector2[] points;
     private List<float> distances = new List<float>();
     private float totalDistance = 0;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         points = new Vector2[segments];

         for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++)
         {
             Vector2 point = GetPathPoint(i / (float) segments);

             if (i > 0)
                 totalDistance += AddSegment(points[i - 1], point);

             points[i] = point;
         }

         totalDistance += AddSegment(points[segments - 1], points[0]);

         StartCoroutine(InitCircles());
     }

     private Vector2 GetPathPoint(float t)
     {
         var angle = t * 360f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
         var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xRadius;
         var y = Mathf.Cos(angle) * yRadius;
         return new Vector2(centerPoint.x + x, centerPoint.y + y);
     }

     private float AddSegment(Vector2 from, Vector2 to)
     {
         float distance = (from - to).sqrMagnitude;
         distances.Add(distance);
         return distance;
     }

     private IEnumerator InitCircles()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

         var time = new WaitForSeconds(totalDistance / speed / numberOfCircles);

         for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++)
         {
             Circle circle = Instantiate(circlePrefab, initPosition, transform.rotation);
             circle.transform.parent = transform;
             circle.name = "circle " + i;
             circle.points = points;
             circle.distances = distances;
             circle.speed = speed;

             yield return time;
         }
     }
 }
```

Circle class:

```c#
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Vector2[] points;
     public float speed = 1f;
     public List<float> distances = new List<float>();

     private float distance = 0;
     private int currentIndex = 0;
     private float time = 0;
     private Vector2 currentPoint;
     private Vector2 nextPoint;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         currentPoint = points[currentIndex];
         nextPoint = points[currentIndex + 1];
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (transform.position == (Vector3) nextPoint)
         {
             currentIndex++;
             currentIndex %= distances.Count;

             time = 0;
             currentPoint = points[currentIndex];
             nextPoint = points[(currentIndex + 1) % points.Length];
         }

         time += Time.deltaTime;
         distance = time * speed / distances[currentIndex];
         transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(currentPoint, nextPoint, distance);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You could have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738064/how-to-place-spheres-in-a-half-circle-shape-between-2-points/56738606#56738606) except using a full circle instead of a half by using `var angle = 2 * Mathf.PI * (i + 1) / (numberOfObjects + 1f);` and you could store the `centerPos + pos` in a `List<Vector3>` for later usage in your routine or wherever you want.

Comment: I don't think you can reuse a `Wait___` object like you're doing.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes you can ! I do cache a single WaitForEndOfFrame() var that I use everywhere in my project, and it's working perfectly fine, so it should be the same for any Waiter I guess

Comment: I had to spawn "n" objects in a circle, it was as simple as taking the 360/n and placing 1 ball at every number from 0 to ballcount * spacing..

Comment: How is it not working. It's hard for us to tell without running this? There could be many problems but we don't know where to look at because you don't mention expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: @user14492 I added links for the actual and expected behavior

Comment: @Jichael WaitForEndOfFrame would have different conditional logic than WaitForSeconds (which would have to track how long its been). But I just gave it a test and it does look like it works. Ok then, not sure how Unity knows to reset the time, but whatever.

Comment: @WaelElSawy Are those screenshots taken when the code in the question is running or the code in my answer?

Comment: @Ruzihm the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your circles may overshoot your destination because you are using `Vector2.Lerp`. Instead, consider finding the minimum between distance you need to travel and the distance left to the next point, and/or using [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) so that you are guaranteed to never overshoot your destination.

You also need to keep track of how far you need to travel and loop until all of the distance you need to travel this frame is covered:

```
 void Update()
 {
     float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

     while (distanceToTravel > 0) 
     {
         if (transform.position == (Vector3) nextPoint)
         {
             currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % distances.Count;

             currentPoint = points[currentIndex];
             nextPoint = points[(currentIndex + 1) % points.Length];
         }

         float distanceThisIteration = Mathf.Min(distanceToTravel,
                 Vector2.Distance(transform.position, nextPoint));

         transform.position = 
                 Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPoint, distanceThisIteration);

         distanceToTravel -= distanceThisIteration;
     }
 }
```

In the code in the question, when/if you do overshoot your destination with `Lerp`, then you will enter a condition `transform.position == (Vector3) nextPoint` will **forever** resolve to `false`.  Using `MoveTowards` instead guarantees that `transform.position == (Vector3) nextPoint` will eventually resolve to true (as long as `speed` is nonzero!).

Also, `Vector2.sqrMagnitude` is not an acceptable way to calculate distance! Use `Vector2.magnitude` or `Vector2.Distance(v1,v2)` instead:

```
 private float AddSegment(Vector2 from, Vector2 to)
 {
     float distance = Vector2.Distance(from, to);
     distances.Add(distance);
     return distance;
 }
```

The last problem is that there is rounding type of error that occurs when using `WaitForSeconds`. From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html):

> There are some factors which can mean the actual amount of time waited does not precisely match the amount of time specified:
>
> 1. Start waiting at the end of the current frame. If you start WaitForSeconds with duration 't' in a long frame (for example, one which has a long operation which blocks the main thread such as some synchronous loading), the coroutine will return 't' seconds after the end of the frame, not 't' seconds after it was called.
> 2. Allow the coroutine to resume on the first frame after 't' seconds has passed, not exactly after 't' seconds has passed.

So since Unity will often resume the coroutine the first frame after `t` seconds have passed, it's actually adding on a fraction of a fraction of a second of an error.  So, each time you yield `WaitForSeconds` in a row, you are adding up that error which leads to the first and the last `Circle` being very close to each other.

To fix this, you can create a coroutine that will create each sphere that begins a `WaitForSeconds` all starting from the same frame:

```
private IEnumerator InitCircles()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);


    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitCreateCircle(i));
    }
}

private IEnumerator WaitCreateCircle(int index)
{
    var time = index * totalDistance / speed / numberOfCircles;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Circle circle = Instantiate(circlePrefab, initPosition, transform.rotation);
    circle.transform.parent = transform;
    circle.name = "circle " + index;
    circle.points = points;
    circle.distances = distances;
    circle.speed = speed;

}
```

Comment: @WaelElSawy I added logic to make sure that the full distance to travel in a frame is traveled. Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I will try it now, but Is it efficient to run `while` loop inside the `update` function?

Comment: I tried your code. It caused an increase to the distances between circles but first and last circle became so close to each other.

Comment: No, `Vector2.Distance(from, to);` did the same behavior.

Comment: @WaelElSawy I was able to reproduce the problem on my end and I eventually found an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: PERFECT! AMAZING!, Thank you so much :)